# How can I add columns in the original data after "groupby" in Pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I am beginner on pandas and stackoverflow.

I have the following data frame and want to:

- identify the top 5 percentile of claims from each state. Output should be policy number, state, claim cost, and fraud score.

original dataframe:

```html
policy_num  state   claim_cost  fraud_score
ABCD1001    CA  4113    0.613
ABCD1002    CA  3946    0.156
ABCD1003    CA  4335    0.014
ABCD1004    CA  3967    0.142
ABCD1005    CA  1599    0.889
ABCD1006    CA  1021    0.873
ABCD1007    CA  1725    0.512
ABCD1008    CA  1794    0.349
ABCD1009    CA  4593    0.574
ABCD1010    CA  3430    0.929
```

Here is my code and result:

```
top5 = fraud_score.sort_values("fraud_score", ascending=False)

final = top5.groupby("state")["fraud_score"].nlargest(5).reset_index()

state   level_1 fraud_score

CA  26  0.988
CA  15  0.964
CA  78  0.963
CA  80  0.951
CA  68  0.948
FL  221 0.988
FL  217 0.961
FL  290 0.939
FL  276 0.923
FL  229 0.923
```

I achieved that 5 top fraud_score each state but I can't add policy_num and claim_cost to it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The original DF has only `CA` state but the result shown also has `FL` which is somewhat surprising! Presumably the original as shown really had more rows. Also note that the sorting is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` to get the columns that you want. `df` is your first dataframe on top of your post.

```
final = df.groupby("state")["fraud_score"].nlargest(5).reset_index()
final_1 = final.merge(df, on=['state', 'fraud_score'], how='left')
print(final_1)

  state  level_1  fraud_score policy_num  claim_cost
0    CA        9        0.929   ABCD1010        3430
1    CA        4        0.889   ABCD1005        1599
2    CA        5        0.873   ABCD1006        1021
3    CA        0        0.613   ABCD1001        4113
4    CA        8        0.574   ABCD1009        4593
```

If you want only specific columns to merge from `df`, you have to specify the columns that you want and the columns that you want to merge. That is columns in `on`.
So for example if you only want `policy_num` the columns are:

```
cols = ['policy_num', 'state', 'fraud_score']
```

And now `merge` with `df`:

```
final_1 = final.merge(df[cols], on=['state', 'fraud_score'], how='left')
```

Comment: No problem :). It is better to post your dataframe as code. For example your first dataframe is hard to reproduce. I suggest something like this:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})`. That way it can be reproduced very quickly.

Comment: Thank you I will pay attentions to it for next questions. I have one more question, If I want to add only policy_num not all columns how would I do it?